# How can I create a ddl for my jpa entities from java code?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ddl

I look for a way how I can create a ddl for my jpa annotated entities.
I prefer a pure java way for this.

If possible it would be nice to have generate the drop statements too.

Comment: This is a repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/297438/auto-generate-data-schema-from-jpa-annotated-entity-classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Export data from a database as sql**

Use the [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) opensource project

> LiquiBase is an open source (LGPL), database-independent library for tracking, managing and applying database changes. It is built on a simple premise: All database changes (structure and data) are stored in an XML-based descriptive manner and checked into source control.

**Generate create and drop script for given JPA entities**

We use this code to generate the drop and create statements:
Just construct this class with all entity classes and call create/dropTableScript.

If needed you can use a persitence.xml and persitance unit name instead. Just say something
and I post the code too.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect;
import org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration;

/**
 * SQL Creator for Tables according to JPA/Hibernate annotations.
 *
 * Use:
 *
 * {@link #createTablesScript()} To create the table creationg script
 *
 * {@link #dropTablesScript()} to create the table destruction script
 * 
 */
public class SqlTableCreator {

    private final AnnotationConfiguration hibernateConfiguration;
    private final Properties dialectProps;

    public SqlTableCreator(final Collection> entities) {

        final Ejb3Configuration ejb3Configuration = new Ejb3Configuration();
        for (final Class entity : entities) {
            ejb3Configuration.addAnnotatedClass(entity);
        }

        dialectProps = new Properties();
        dialectProps.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect");

        hibernateConfiguration = ejb3Configuration.getHibernateConfiguration();
    }

    /**
     * Create the SQL script to create all tables.
     * 
     * @return A {@link String} representing the SQL script.
     */
    public String createTablesScript() {
        final StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();

        final String[] creationScript = hibernateConfiguration.generateSchemaCreationScript(Dialect
                .getDialect(dialectProps));
        for (final String string : creationScript) {
            script.append(string).append(";\n");
        }
        script.append("\ngo\n\n");

        return script.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Create the SQL script to drop all tables.
     * 
     * @return A {@link String} representing the SQL script.
     */
    public String dropTablesScript() {
        final StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();

        final String[] creationScript = hibernateConfiguration.generateDropSchemaScript(Dialect
                .getDialect(dialectProps));
        for (final String string : creationScript) {
            script.append(string).append(";\n");
        }
        script.append("\ngo\n\n");

        return script.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is it possible to use a persistence.xml?

Answer (score 3):

DataNucleus has SchemaTool that can be invoked from java, or from the command line. It does what you require

--Andy ([DataNucleus](http://www.datanucleus.org))

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate has built-in support for this. See **org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport**.

Answer (score 2):

OpenJPA has support for this too. The OpenJPA [mapping tool](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/latest/docs/manual/manual.html#ref_guide_mapping_mappingtool) can create a script or create a ddl file. The ddl should work with other JPA implementations (although each vendor has a few quirks).

If you're using OpenJPA as a persistence provider you can configure OpenJPA to create the tables the first time they're needed by adding the SynchronizeMappings property to persistence.xml.

Example :

```
<persistence-unit name="test"> 
    <!--
       . . .
      -->
    <properties>
        <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings"
                  value="buildSchema"/>
    </properties>
    <!--
       . . .
      -->
</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an explaination of how to use the hibernate SchemaExport class to do exactly what you want.

http://jandrewthompson.blogspot.com/2009/10/how-to-generate-ddl-scripts-from.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this still a reasonable way to generate DDL from Java classes?  I'm asking because the code pointed to by the link is about 10 years old now and many of the classes it uses have been deprecated.