# How to generate an ordered ddl for SQL Server 2008 R2 using JAVA?

Tags: java, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 and generating a ddl file with scripts for all objects of database like tables, functions, triggers, procedures, views, constraints, etc.

**Now my requirement** is to generate this ddl file in alphabetically order for database objects and all queries for an object type should be grouped together.

That is:-

```
Drop Table A1
Create Table A1
Alter Table A1

Drop Table B1
Create Table B1
Alter Table B1

Drop Function F1
Create Function F1

Drop Procedure P1
Create Procedure P1 and so on..
```

The queries are executed perfectly from code as It is handled in code according to a sequence.

**ISSUE**: When I execute the SQL file directly on database in same order, I got following two issue.

**case one:**
Table B1's primary key is the foreign key of Table A1. In this case, if we execute the SQL file directly on database then the Alter Table A1 query will give error

`Cannot find the object "B1" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.`

in execution as table B1 is not yet created.

**case two:**
Table A1's primary key is the foreign key of Table B1. In this case the Drop Table A1 query will give error

`Could not drop object 'A1' because it is referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3726)`

in execution if we execute the SQL file directly on database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because of circular foreign keys like that, most DDL generators will create all tables first, including primary keys and maybe indexes, *then*, once all tables have been created, foreign keys are added using `ALTER TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

Start from an already constructed database schema. Point [Hibernate reverse engineering tool](http://omtlab.com/java-hibernate-reverse-engineering-eclipse-tutorial/) to create entity model. Then [create DDL from generated entities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1065002/32090). The ordering will be correct.