# Can Hibernate design tables automatically

Tags: hibernate, orm

I know that Hibernate can create tables automatically, if the mapping from the domain model to columns is specified.

I am interested to know if Hibernate can actually create/design the table schema based on the domain model as well. For example I have classes that often have properties that are variable length collections e.g. **Set** or **ArrayList** and I am curious to know how Hibernate would "design" the tables to fit these properties. But first I'd like to know if this is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these answer your question:

[Reverse engineer DDL from JPA entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779479/reverse-engineer-ddl-from-jpa-entities)

[Auto generate data schema from JPA annotated entity classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297438/auto-generate-data-schema-from-jpa-annotated-entity-classes)